# How to debug timeout failures made in Play?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework-2.0

I have written an app that makes HTTP requests on a regular basis using Play's async WS library. The whole thing works perfectly 99%. However in some cases it simply timeouts.

I have no clue on how to debug this. What tools, what methods can I use to debug this situation? I would like to know if this is software related, hardware, network congestion...

The timeout is handled using Akka `firstCompletedOf`. As below :

```
// Where f and timeoutFuture are two Future[Unit]
Future.firstCompletedOf(f :: timeoutFuture :: Nil).onComplete {
```

The second part of information is the call is made in an Akka actor.

Comment: Can you share the code you are executing?